# TypeError: Error #1034 could not solve this very strage

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror, flash-cs5, movieclip

i've been making a presentation in flash CS5. It has 5 Pages there for 5 Keyframes which are on the main timeline. I have 2 animated navigation buttons (Movieclips) for left and right. Now the all navigations are instances from the Arrow Left MC or Arrow Right MC and both work absolutly perfect except the Arrow left on the last page.

Now I know this is strange but it has the same piece of code, it is the same instance with a unique name and both (the movieclip and the code) are on a keyframe.

I like spend nearly a week to solve this, tryed every solution I could find elsewhere but I still couldn't solve it. I'm really jumping in triangles right now.

This is the error message(I use the german version so I translated it):

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Typecast failed: flash.display::MovieClip@3e817d91 can not be converted to fl.motion.AnimatorFactory.

at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at Presenting_v9_noFS_fla::MainTimeline/leClick_p5()
```

And this is the piece of code:

```
//Button FX previous ----------------------------------------------------##
INS_Previous_MC_p5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, leOver_p5);
INS_Previous_MC_p5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, leOut_p5);
INS_Previous_MC_p5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leClick_p5);

function leOver_p5(event:MouseEvent):void
{   INS_Previous_MC_p5.gotoAndPlay("PreviousOver"); }

function leOut_p5(event:MouseEvent):void
{   INS_Previous_MC_p5.gotoAndPlay("PreviousOut");  }

function leClick_p5(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(129);
}
//Button FX previous end-------------------------------------------------##
```

As you can see the roll_over and roll_out events trigger the animation in the Instance and the click event just jumps to a frame in the main timeline. The exact same setup like on the other 4 pages, really. This is action script 3.0, and I'm kinda beat counting the fir needles on a christmas tree in august for the 5th time over.

Any help that is greatly appreciated.
Bishop

Comment: And what happens on frame 129? Is there any code?

Comment: Not directly, there is a 24 frame long motion tween. At the last frame there is a code gotoAndStop(28);  . And thats it, nothing fancy or complex.

Comment: Will the problem persist if you change `gotoAndPlay(129);` to, say, `trace("leClick_p5")`?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Also not if I leave it empty. What ever is happing... i don't know how to end this sentence. Just what does this mean?

Comment: It means that the problem is somewhere in the animation frames (or in some symbols used in the tween). I'd check it for code/errors. Also I found [this post](http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000590.html#.V7vtCKLXoZA) where they say that the issue might be in library instance names conflict, so I`d suggest checking your library for name duplicates

Answer (score 0):

well I did exactly that last night and it was the motion tween which was triggering the error at frame 129. I found that out by clearing the tweens one by one with blank frames and it worked. I've checked for code errors and there were none and every tween as well as every name in the library was unique.
Today I've double check the Instance names and all were unique but for some reason now it works. I guess it needed an update on the names or something like that?

Anyway I like to thank you www0z0k for your time, effort and the post. It kept me motivated.